# Error handling in firebase once call javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am doing a query in firebase database with one call. If the record exists in firebase then do some code, but when the record doesn't exist error handling never gets called. What is wrong?

```
dbReference.child('432sfdgS24').once('value', function(snap) {
    console.log(snap.val()); // logged if '432sfdgS24' exists   
}, function(error) {
    console.error(error); // never come here even if '432sfdgS24'does not exist
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Missing data at a location is not an error.  A request for data at a location with no data, should just result in a snapshot that contains no data.

An error happens when the client is sure it will not be able to read the data at a location because a security rule on the server prevents it.

Answer (score 0):

when you fetch data from firebase database, you won't get error. If the data exists, you can access it as `snap.val()`, if data does not exist then `snap.val()` will be null.

So you can do this,

```
dbReference.child('432sfdgS24').once('value', function(snap) {
    var data = snap.val()
    if(data != null) {
        console.log('Data fetched successfully')
    }
    else {
        console.log('Failed to fetch the data')
    }
})
```